# AddressSanitizer crashes on stackoverflow when trying to intercept __iso99_sprintf()

Tags: c++, hook, address-sanitizer

I am running on Linux RedHat 8.1, libasan 8.5.0-18, GCC 8.5.0.

When running two different elf's on the same machine, using `LD_PRELOAD=path/to/libasan` one is working well and creates a log, but the other one crashes, when running under gdb I see that it fails to intercept `__isoc99_sprintf` function and then runs in infinite loop of `dlsym, _dlerror_run, free` until it crashes.

```
#151180 0x00007ffff36c4163 in dlsym () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#151181 0x0000000012510a63 in free ()
#151182 0x00007ffff36c46b3 in _dlerror_run () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#151183 0x00007ffff36c4163 in dlsym () from /lib64/libdl.so.2
#151184 0x00007ffff6f1d560 in __interception::GetRealFunctionAddress (func_name=func_name@entry=0x7ffff6f3a5d2 "__isoc99_sprintf", func_addr=func_addr@entry=0x7ffff7376368 <__interception::real___isoc99_sprintf>, real=real@entry=140737335620192, wrapper=wrapper@entry=140737335620192) at ../../../../libsanitizer/interception/interception_linux.cc:29
#151185 0x00007ffff6ed9ab1 in InitializeCommonInterceptors () at ../../../../libsanitizer/sanitizer_common/sanitizer_common_interceptors.inc:6304
#151186 __asan::InitializeAsanInterceptors () at ../../../../libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:555
#151187 0x00007ffff6efde50 in __asan::AsanInitInternal () at ../../../../libsanitizer/asan/asan_rtl.cc:410
#151188 __asan::AsanInitInternal () at ../../../../libsanitizer/asan/asan_rtl.cc:368
#151189 0x00007ffff6e3832c in __interceptor___cxa_atexit (func=0x7ffff262a250 <std::(anonymous namespace)::generic_error_category::~generic_error_category()>, arg=0x7ffff2927190, dso_handle=0x7ffff291b800) at ../../../../libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:534
#151190 0x00007ffff2628b7a in _GLOBAL__sub_I_compatibility_c__0x.cc () from /lib64/libstdc++.so.6
#151191 0x00007ffff7dd6f1a in call_init (l=<optimized out>, argc=argc@entry=1, argv=argv@entry=0x7fffffffe2c8, env=env@entry=0x7fffffffe2d8) at dl-init.c:72
#151192 0x00007ffff7dd701a in call_init (env=0x7fffffffe2d8, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8, argc=1, l=<optimized out>) at dl-init.c:30
#151193 _dl_init (main_map=0x7ffff7ffe210, argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe2c8, env=0x7fffffffe2d8) at dl-init.c:119
#151194 0x00007ffff7debc8a in _dl_start_user () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
#151195 0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#151196 0x00007fffffffe532 in ?? ()
#151197 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

I tried to use ASAN_OPTIONS environment variable to cancel the interception of this function but with no success.

Analyzing the elf with `strings binary-file | grep GCC` shows it has been compiled with GCC 8.5 and GCC 4.4.7.
Address Sanitizer is part of GCC starting from version 4.8.

How can I solve this conflict? or is there anything else that can cause this issue?

Comment: How do you build your app with the enabled address sanitizer?

Comment: @273K I don't build it, it's an existing elf file that I use LD_PRELOAD to ensure the address sanitizer .so file is loaded into its memory space

Comment: Is this `libasan` some sort of `valgrind`-alternative? If so, try valgrind, it will find some problems in your program.

Comment: Asan runtimes are incompatible across GCC versions. Is there a chance that you are preloading newer libasan.so into binary compiled with older GCC or vice verse?